# How to keep only a particular string using regex on notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation

I'm trying to keep some data using regex on notepad++, but I cannot find the right regex expression to do it:

This is my data:

```
Procédure PL/SQL terminée.

950806067 26950073200020 NON EXISTANTE - INSERTION EFFECTUEE - ID ROR : 199348

Procédure PL/SQL terminée.

950808519 38301912200019 NON EXISTANTE - INSERTION EFFECTUEE - ID ROR : 199349
```

Well, I want to keep only the number after ":" which is "19...."

Actually, I know how to delete this string `19\d+$`, but I don't know how to keep it. I tried with `[^19\d+$]` and other expressions but nothing works. It's a bit complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a simple find and replace:

**Find:**

```
Procédure PL/SQL terminée.(?:\r\n?|\r)(?:\r\n?|\r).*?ID ROR : (\d+)(?:\r\n?|\r)?
```

**Replace:**

```
$1
```

**Output:**

```
209348
199349
```

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve that with 1 single regex replacement:

```
.*\h(19\d+$\R?)\R*|.+\R*
```

and replace with

```
\1
```

**Details**:

- `.*\h(19\d+$\R?)\R*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible (`.*`) up to the last horizontal whitespace (`\h`) and then followed with `19` + one or more digits (`\d+`) at the end of the line (`$`) + an optional line break (`\R?`) (that are captured into Group 1) followed with 0+ line breaks (`\R*`)
- `|` - or
- `.+\R*` - any 1+ chars other than line break chars followed with 0+ line breaks

The replacement pattern only contains the backreference to Group 1 (`\1` or `$1`) that will re-insert the contents of Group 1 back into the resulting text. The rest will be removed.

[image]

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: See *Well, I want to keep only the number after ":" which is **"19...."***. Anyway, remove `19` and you will get any numbers at the end of the string after the last space.